# Set xmodmap control modifier combination

Tags: xmodmap

What is the syntax for making `ctrl+q` emit `KP_7`? How to revert it back?

I've read the man page but it does not provide example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use xdotool instead of modmap wich can change single keys, not combination keys.
Example: set a shortcut for `xdotool key KP-7`